# EasyUI: Groups in Combobox

Tags: jquery-easyui

EasyUI version 1.3.3:
I would like to know how I can set the valueField (i.e. what will be displayed in the combobox after the user selects an option) to be a mix of the group name & the item name (e.g. Grp1-item1).

```
var data = [
        {group:'Group1',items:[
            {value:'v11',text:'Option11'},
            {value:'v12',text:'Option12'},
            {value:'v13',text:'Option13'},
            {value:'v14',text:'Option14'}
        ]},
        {group:'Group2',items:[
            {value:'v21',text:'Option21'},
            {value:'v22',text:'Option22'},
            {value:'v23',text:'Option23'},
            {value:'v24',text:'Option24'}
        ]}
    ];
    function loadFilter(data){
        var dd = [];
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var group = data[i].group;
            dd.push({
                group:group,
                text:group
            });
            dd = dd.concat(data[i].items);
        }
        return dd;
    }
    function onLoadSuccess(){
        var groupItems = $(this).combobox('panel').find('div.combobox-item:has(span.combobox-group-text)');
        groupItems.removeClass('combobox-item');
    }
    function formatter(row){
        if (row.group){
            return '<span class="combobox-group-text" style="font-weight:bold">'+row.group+'</span>';
        } else {
            return '<span style="padding-left:10px">'+row.text+'</span>';
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        $('#cc').combobox({
            data:data,
            loadFilter:loadFilter,
            formatter:formatter,
            onLoadSuccess:onLoadSuccess
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use a formatter, concatenate the group and item and return it

```
formatter:function(value,row,index){
  return row.Group+'('+row.Item+')';
}
```